# Automatically Including LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 when creating new database

Tags: django

I have to type

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

everytime i create a new database for the django app. Is it possible to avoid this? What should i do to avoid this?

Need some guidance on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the bash_profile file in your home directory and add the two statements in it...

Comment: I'm create and manipulate Postgres DB from posgres user which hasn't home dir. How I can do this?